# Finding pixel width in matlab

Tags: matlab, width, pixel

In order to find the **pixel width**, how can I do that in `matlab`?

**EDIT** I need the width in say for example *mm*

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to find the pixel width of?

Comment: @Brian L. I just simply have a `jpg` image, and just want to know what is the width of the pixels in that image. Thanks

Comment: @Brian L. I mean in terms like size in `mm` (I made an edit in my question)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Pixels in JPGs don't define the physical width of the image; the resolution of the monitor it's displayed on does, and the DPI setting of the printer you print it on does, etc. But showing the same JPG on a different monitor or printing it on a different printer will usually change its physical size. So could you better explain what you mean with an image's "pixel width in mm"?

Comment: Based on your handle, I assume you are trying to figure out the physical extents of an object/shape you segmented out in a JPG file? If so, you would need a much more detailed question! (ie one pixel in a JPG file could represent any 'area' in the real world, depends on the zoom/lens/other acquisition parameters).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`ScreenPixelsPerInch`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/rootobject_props.html#zmw57dd0e355460) property of the root object.

```
pixelsPerInch = get(0, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');
mmPerInch     = 25.4;
mmPerPixel    = mmPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
```