# How do i extract coordinates of pixel edges/corners

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I understand pixel elements are stored at the center of the cells. However, i need to work with coordinates at the edges and corners rather than the center coordinates.

[image]

The code could be used to extract all the internal nodes shown in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeVhz.png)

```
%obtain the pixel width
pixelsPerInch = get(0, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');
mmPerInch     = 25.4;
mmPerPixel    = mmPerInch / pixelsPerInch; 

[nrow, ncol] = size(Img);

for ii = 1: nrow - 1
  for jj = 1: ncol - 1
    % determine the distance of each pixel from the origin
    x_mm(jj) = jj * mmPerPixel;
    y_mm(ii) = ii * mmPerPixel;

    % determine the nodal coordinates
    node_x(jj) = (x_mm(jj) + (mmPerPixel/2))/mmPerPixel;
    node_y(ii) = (y_mm(ii) + (mmPerPixel/2))/mmPerPixel;

  end
end

%%%%% merge the x and y-coords
[node_y, node_x] = meshgrid(node_y, node_x);
my_nodes         = [node_y(:), node_x(:)];
```

In order to find the edge centres above, below, or on each sides of any node, all that is required is to add or subtract 1/2 from the node_x, node_y depending on the direction one intends to go. For instance, to find the edge above any node, do the following:

```
jx = node_x;
iy = node_y - 0.5;
```

One can as well find the pixel centres from each node of interest by deciding if to add/subtract 1/2 from the x and y-coords of the point of interest.

Comment: Not sure what **Matlab** folks do, but with **ImageMagick**, you just add `1/2` to each coordinate... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#coordinates

Comment: @MarkSetchell Depending on what the OP wants his final output to look like (in units of `mm` or `inches` on his display, perhaps), that wouldn't suffice. You have to do a bit of post-processing after adding/subtracting `1/2` from a pixel's coordinate in the image matrix to convert it into a meaningful unit of distance.

Comment: This just corresponds to shifts of a half pixel. In many application, the distinction is irrelevant. In others, there is no need to adjust the individual coordinates, you just do it as a post-processing of the results, where applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're working with images and their pixel coordinates, this answer assumes that you have access to `MATLAB's Image Processing Toolbox`.

From MATLAB's [`Image Coordinate Systems` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html):

> The intrinsic coordinates (x,y) of the center point of any pixel are identical to the column and row indices for that pixel. For example, the center point of the pixel in row 5, column 3 has spatial coordinates x = 3.0, y = 5.0.
>
> [image: Intrinsic Pixel Coordinate System]

First, find the width of each pixel (in whichever units your interested in). [Another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13448934/5209610) has already illustrated how this is done:

> [T]he ScreenPixelsPerInch property of the root object.
>
> ```
> pixelsPerInch = get(0, 'ScreenPixelsPerInch');
> mmPerInch     = 25.4;
> mmPerPixel    = mmPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
> ```

Then, convert the pixel's position in your image matrix (let's use the example from MATLAB's docs of row 5 and column 3 -> `x = 3.0`, `y = 5.0`) by doing something like `x_mm = 3.0 * mmPerPixel` and `y = 5.0 * mmPerPixel`.

If you want any of the positions of the corners, just add / subtract `mmPerPixel / 2` to the `x_mm` and `y_mm` variables, and you have determined the spatial positioning of the corners (or edges, take your pick) of the pixels in your image matrix.

**EDIT**

To extract the spatial coordinates of the right-hand corners of all the pixels you are interested in:

```
% 2-D locations of pixels of interest
pixelLocations = [2,4;2,3;2,2;3,2;4,1;5,1;6,1;6,2;6,3];
% XY coordinates of all pixels of interest
pixelPositions = sub2ind(size(SegI), pixelLocations(:,1), pixelLocations(:,2));   

% Convert XY coordinates into millimeters
nodeCoords = SegI(pixelsPositions) .* mmPerPixel;
% Since mmPerPixel is the full width & length of each pixel, this value corresponds with the upper-right hand corner of each pixel (i.e., each node)

% Offset nodeCoords by half of their height & width to obtain pixelCoords
pixelCoords = pixelCoord - [mmPerPixel/2, mmPerPixel/2];
```

Comment: Many thanks @Vladislav. I do appreciate your help, but i am a little bit confused with the conversion. Since 1inch = 25.4mm, shouldn't mmPerInch be = 1 divided by 25.4? Also, from my understanding, it seems that the 'ScreenPixelPerInch' is a function of the screen's resolution?

Comment: Thank you so much @Vladislav.. I do get it now. I got a distance of 0.2646mm for each pixel (my pixelsPerInch = 96). From your figure above, that means from origin to pixel (1,1) = 0.2646mm, hence adding 0.2646/2 to this distance (on both axes) will give me the node at (1.5, 1.5). I still have a little difficulty just now - which is to find the coordinates of all nodes of interest (blue & green) at a go. Please, any more help/suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Vladislav. I think there is probably a bug in your suggested code as i got the `node_coords_mm = [0.3969 0.3969]` whereas, the answer should be: `[x  y] = [0.3969 0.926]` Can you please check through again? Many thanks.

Comment: See what I tried that worked for that red node: 
`M = size(Seg_I, 1);
N = size(Seg_I, 2);
 
linear_indices = sub2ind(size(Seg_I), 3, 1);
[row, col]        = ind2sub(size(Seg_I), linear_indices);
 
pixelCoord  = [col row].* mmPerPixel;

cornerCoord = pixelCoord + [mmPerPixel/2, mmPerPixel/2];`

My thoughts now is to find a way to **store all linear indices** of the image, and then I can easily loop through those to find all the nodal points.

Comment: See my newest edit. There's nothing wrong with your approach (aside from some confusion about rows and columns), all you need to do is put all those subscripts into a matrix (as I've done). The additional step where you re-convert linear indices back into 2-D subscripts isn't necessary (see my edit, I didn't do that). Also, your `pixelCoord` isn't intuitive - rows are generally a dimension to the left of columns.

Comment: @gary105 That's great to hear! Perhaps you could update your question to include working code that you've used to solve your problem.

Comment: What i actually wanted was to extract the coordinates of all the internal nodes and  i was able to figure out how to adapt the help you provided here to the specific problem. Nevertheless, if you still want, i could  post the code here.